# Use async series and parallel with exported function in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I'm trying to get my code to run using the async module. However, when the async.series runs, it only executes the third() function then stops. I understand that the first argument of async.series takes an array of tasks that requires a callback. However, I'm unsure as to how I'm supposed to do a callback on a function that I've exported from another file as in the functions first() and second(). Any help?

#### process.js:

```
var process = require('child_process');

function executeProcess() {
  process.exec(...);
}

exports.Process = function() {
  executeProcess();
}
```

#### app.js

```
var process = require('./process.js');

function first() {
  process.Process();
}

function second() {
  process.Process();
}

function third() {
  console.log('third');
}

function parallel() {
  async.parallel([first, second], function() {
    console.log('first and second in parallel');
  });
}

async.series([third, parallel], function() {
  console.log('third then parallel');
});
```

Comment: Well, your `Process` and `executeProcess` functions need to take a callback that they invoke once your process has finished. Check out the docs of `process.exec(...)` to see how this is done.

Answer (score 0):

You should use callback functions. I think your process.js is ok so I have not changed it. But I made some minor changes in the app.js. Just added there callback functions:

```js
var process = require('./process.js');
var async = require("async");

function first(callback) {
    console.log('FIRST');
    process.Process();
    callback();
}

function second(callback) {
    console.log('SECOND');
    process.Process();
    callback();
}

function third(callback) {
  console.log('third');
  callback();
}

function parallel() {
  async.parallel([first, second], function(callback) {
    console.log('first and second in parallel');
  });
}

async.series([third, parallel], function() {
  console.log('third then parallel');
});
```

This should work. Here is an very good blogpost about async library:

[Node.js async in practice: When to use what?](http://www.sebastianseilund.com/nodejs-async-in-practice)